# Calling record set within mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in which i have to use one select statement at three places. Can i optimize that using any other way so i can store result set somewhere in variable and use it later in my query.

```
WHERE tbl1.user_id IN(SELECT to_user_id FROM tbl_tblthird WHERE from_user_id=userIdIn) OR tbl1.user_id=userIdIn

WHERE tbl2.`user_id`IN(SELECT to_user_id FROM tbl_third WHERE from_user_id=userIdIn)

WHERE tbl1.user_id IN(SELECT to_user_id FROM tblthird WHERE from_user_id=userIdIn)
```

the query  `SELECT to_user_id FROM tblthird WHERE from_user_id=userIdIn` returns number of records. If i can store in var or record set and use it then in places where it occured.

any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

use can hold it into a variable and add it to the query like

```
variable vQuery = " where condition";

select * from table1 " + vQuery;
select * from table2 " + vQuery;
select * from table3 " + vQuery;
```